# Add chapters to m4a (mp4) files

Tags: audio, mp4, aac

I used ChapterTool from Apple, but it's broken and discontinued since 2005..
Is there any other similar command line tool, or library (I'm writing in ruby..) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[atomicparsley](http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net) is great. I've used it a lot.